# Resistance and power requirements for a current-limiting resistor

Tags: led, power, voltage, resistors, watts

I'm making my electronics project.

I need answer please
I need an resistor 
I just need to clarify and validate.
Given

- \$V_s\$-15 V
- \$V_{LED}\$-3.5 V
- \$I_{LED}\$ - 25 mA

I did:

R= \$\frac{V_s - V_{led} }{I_{led}}\$

= \$\frac{11.5 V}{25mA}\$
 = \$\frac{11.5 V}{0.025 A}\$
 = \$460 \Omega\$

And a power of 0.2875W, but I bought 470 \$\Omega\$ with 1 W

What will happen to my project?
Fail or burn the LEDs?

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering StackExchange! Please note how Renan has edited your question to make it easier to read. If you follow these practices in the future you will be much more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: but how can anyone read my question properly if the calculations are edited like it became R= \$\frac{V_s-V_{Led}}\s from R = Sv-Ledv/Ledc

Comment: Questions and answers on EE.SE use the MathJax system of markup, so that equations look as they should in your browser. If you are seeing the "\$" in your browser then you have some kind of problem See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Strazey You might need to make sure Javascript is enabled and that you're allowing scripts from mathjax.org to run. These format equations beyond what the text editor can offer on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1W resistor exceeds the power requirement so that's perfectly fine. The only time you run into problems is if you use a resistor with a lower power rating. For example if you used a 0.25W rated resistor it may not be able to dissipate enough heat, get too hot and fail.

On the resistance side 470 ohms will cause a little less current to flow than the theoretical value of 460 ohms you've calculated, so other than delivering a little under 25mA that's fine as well. The approximately 0.5mA lower current won't make a visible difference.

Comment: Also remember that nothing is exact. That 1W resistor probably has a stated tolerance of 5% (and your calculations should too), so you're pretty much where you want to be.

Comment: @lyndon, true, thought about adding that but thought I'd keep to the main point to keep it simple. They'd also be the issue of manufacturing differences between the LEDs changing the apparently brightness as well.

Comment: So there will be no future problems that I will be meet on my project?

Comment: @StrazeyStriker, no the above will be fine and exactly what I'd do. It's generally safer to error on the side of a higher power rating and lowering current, which is exactly what you've done for this sort of situation.

Comment: I love this community I wish it always be free.
I love this community because a lot of persons will answer your question
Thanks for validating my question

Thank You
 I guess I will close this question and marked as answered